# SEDE download link returns a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Trying to download the data dump from the [help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) of SEDE yields a 404 when clicking on the [download button](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent). (Shouldn't it link [here](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/) instead?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, yeah, the data dump is no longer one single massive file, so linking to the index makes sense. [Done now](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/84), pending a merge & deploy.